# Oracle MapViewer Secure Map Rendering - web_user_info

Tags: java, oracle, cookies

I am working on an Oracle Forms application where a MapViewer Java Bean is embedded to show a map from Oracle Spatial. I want to use the secure map rendering using web_user_info package. By default it takes web application user name from a parameter J2EE_USER. A manual cookie can be used to set web_user_type parameter while creating a data source for MapViewer. I want to know how we can create a cookie / use an existing one (if any) to get the database user name of user logged on to the forms application?